# What is the brief period of abandonment referred to in Isaiah 54:7?:

Tags: isaiah

What is the brief period, specifically?

> [Isa 54:7 NLT] (7) "For a brief moment I abandoned you, but with great compassion I will take you back.

Comment: "For a brief moment I abandoned you[Jerusalem], but with great compassion, I will take you back. The brief period refers to the 70 years exile of Jerusalem when the Babylonian forces destroyed the temple and took them captives to Babylon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hebrew verb  קָבַץ (qabats = "gather") shows an interesting pattern.  It is used to describe the gathering of numerous things; but, when used to describe Israel and Judah especially, it is almost unanimously describing the gathering of the Jews after the Babylonian exile from the surrounding nations, or, the people gathering for repentance and renewal of their faith.  Here is a sample:

- 1 Chron 11:1 - Then all Israel **gathered** to David at Hebron and said, "Behold, we are your bone and your flesh.
- 1 Chron 16:35 - Cry out, "Save us, God our Savior; **gather** us and deliver us from the nations, that we may give thanks to your holy name, and glory in your praise."
- 2 Chron 15:9 - He **gathered** all Judah and Benjamin and those from Ephraim, Manasseh and Simeon who resided with them, for many defected to him from Israel when they saw that the LORD his God was with him.
- 2 Chron 20:4 - So Judah **gathered** together to seek help from the LORD; they even came from all the cities of Judah to seek the LORD.

Deut 30:1-4 is a prophecy by Moses of the (then) future apostasy of Israel and they promise of God gathering them back when they repented.  Neh 1:9 quotes or alludes to this prophecy and Ezra 7:28, 8:15 sees its actual fulfillment using the same verb.  Here are a few more examples:

- Jer 23:3 - "Then I Myself will **gather** the remnant of My flock out of all the countries where I have driven them and bring them back to their pasture, and they will be fruitful and multiply.
- Jer 29:14 - 'I will be found by you,' declares the LORD, 'and I will restore your fortunes and will **gather** you from all the nations and from all the places where I have driven you,' declares the LORD, 'and I will bring you back to the place from where I sent you into exile.'
- Jer 31:8, 10 - Behold, I am bringing them from the north country, And I will **gather** them from the remote parts of the earth, Among them the blind and the lame, The woman with child and she who is in labor with child, together; A great company, they will return here. ... Hear the word of the LORD, O nations, And declare in the coastlands afar off, And say, “He who scattered Israel will **gather** him And keep him as a shepherd keeps his flock.”

See also Jer 40:15, 49:14, Eze 11:17, 20:34, etc.

Isa 54:7, 8 also uses the same verb:

> "For a brief moment I forsook you, But with great compassion I will
> **gather** you.  "In an outburst of anger I hid My face from you for a
> moment, But with everlasting lovingkindness I will have compassion on
> you," Says the LORD your Redeemer.

Thus, Isaiah appears to look forward to the time when Israel will be again gathered from the surrounding nations to be made an independent nation again.

The Pulpit commentary observes:

> Verses 7, 8. - For a small moment have I forsaken thee. The sixty or
> seventy years of the Captivity were but as a moment of time compared
> with the long ages during which God had tenderly watched over and
> protected his Church, and, still more, compared with the eternity
> during which he was now about to show himself her constant Guardian
> and Protector.

Matthew Pooles has:

> For a small moment; for the space of some few years, as seventy years
> in Babylon, and some such intervals, which may well be called a small
> moment in comparison of God’s everlasting kindness mentioned in the
> next verse.
>
> Forsaken thee; withdrawn my favour and help from thee, and left thee
> in thine enemies’ hands.
>
> With great mercies, such as are most precious and sweet for quality,
> as is here said, and such as are of long continuance, as is said in
> the following verse, will I gather thee from all the places where thou
> art dispersed, from all the parts of the world.

Barnes has this:

> The reference here is probably to the captivity at Babylon, when they
> were apparently forsaken by Yahweh. Though to them this appeared long,
> yet compared with their subsequent prosperity, it was but an instant
> of time.

Ellicott has:

> (7) For a small moment.—Historically the words point to the seventy
> years of exile, as being but a transient interruption of the
> manifestation of the everlasting mercies. Spiritually they have wider
> and manifold fulfilments in the history of individuals, of the Church,
> of mankind.

Comment: Awesome answer.

Comment: That brings an interesting background to: *[Luk 13:34-35 NASB] (34) "O Jerusalem, Jerusalem, [the city] that kills the prophets and stones those sent to her! How often I wanted to gather your children together, just as a hen [gathers] her brood under her wings, and you would not [have it!] (35) "Behold, your house is left to you [desolate;] and I say to you, you will not see Me until [the time] comes when you say, 'BLESSED IS HE WHO COMES IN THE NAME OF THE LORD!'"*